# Ruby: Return hash value within stub

Tags: ruby, chefspec

How do I correctly return the hash object from the stub so that I don't always get the error message "NoMethoderror: undefined method 'each' for nil: NilClass"?

```
# ruby code to test
env_json = JSON.parse(Chef::ServerAPI.new.get("test").to_json)
env_json ['versions'].each do |name, version|
  # things to do
end
```

Within my tests, I want to mock the serverAPI call.

```
before(:each) do
  query = double
  allow(query).to receive(:get) do |arg1|
    case arg1.downcase
    when %r{\test}
     {"versions" => { "flag2" => false } } ## return hash value
    else
     {"versions2" => { "flag2" => true } } ## return hash value
    end
  end
  allow(Chef::ServerAPI).to receive(:new).and_return(query) 
end
```

Does anyone have an idea how I have to pass the hash value in the query?

Comment: Not sure what the exact issue is but what I can tell you is that your regex for "test" is actually looking for a [tab] character followed by "est".

Comment: What is the output of
`JSON.parse(Chef::ServerAPI.new.get("test").to_json)`
error indicates that `['versions']` returns nil

Small tip: try this notation is much clearer 
`{ versions: { flag2: false } }`